# How to delete '\n' from items of a list

Tags: python, data-mining, data-cleaning, tf-idf, topic-modeling

I am going to remove '\n' (new line) from items of a list. the following commands read data from an excel file in DataFrame format, then convert it into a list 'bodylist':

```
data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\thmag\HealthUnlockSelenium\PopularPosts\out2.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['body'])
#print (df)

#convert df to list
bodylist = df.values.tolist()
bodylist= map(lambda s: s.strip(),bodylist)
for item in bodylist:
    
    print (item)
```

But I have the following error :

```
 bodylist= map(lambda s: s.strip(),bodylist)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: Did you try checking what `bodylist` looks like before the attempt? The items of the list are themselves lists. So, think about how you would handle *that*, and then apply that to the overall data.

Comment: each record is list and not string , if you print bodylist the result would look like [['record1'],['record2']..]

Comment: It seems strange that read_excel keeps \n at the end, how did you saw that they were there ?

Comment: When I print bodylist, I would see '\n'

Comment: Would you please let me know how I can change the bodylist into this format ['data','data',data',....] @qaiser

Comment: Is there some explicit "\n" in the XLSX content ? Like as string inside some cells

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi you can use [''.join(x) for x in bodylist]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
bodylist = df.values.tolist()
bodylist = [elt.replace("\n", "") for elt in bodylist]
```

Given you have a list, you browse it with comprehension and create a new list without the «\n» character.

Comment: Maybe you can add a quick explanation what your code does and how a list comprehension works so that the OP better understands your answer.

Comment: I have the same error that 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'.                    I have an excel file including 923 records of textual data. I am going to clean the data for the next step d the excel file which is topic modeling. I read the excel file in DataFrame format, then convert it into a list. Now I am going to remove '\n' because each new line in the excel file converts into '\n' in python. Now, I need help to see what is the best approach to remove '\n'

Comment: Many thanks your suggestion works with a bit change

Answer (score 0):

```
df['body'] = df['body'].apply(lambda line: line.replace('\n', ''))
```

This code will perform the operation within the dataframe itself, `apply` takes a function or a lambda action and will perform it over every row in the dataframe.

If you need the list representation after that you can convert it to a list.

Comment: Many thanks, I did what you suggest but I have still '\n' in output.

Comment: @TaherehMaghsoudi : Sorry I think strip('\n') Will get you where you want , strip by default works on space

Comment: replace("\n",'') is more apt here I assumed you only wanted to remove the lines at the beginning or ending of a sentence